# Which connector should I use between the power supply and the Einsy board?

Tags: prusa-i3, prusa-i3-rework, wire-type

I am looking for a way to easily separate the wires between the power supply and the Einsy board of my Prusa Mk 3S+ with a connector. The power supply delivers 10 A at 24 V.

I thought about a [YL wire-to-wire electrical connector](https://www.jst.com/products/wire-to-wire/yl-connector/) as it can handle up to 7 A at 300 V. This should be enough since the two cables share the total load.

[image]

The 6 cables (4 power cables & 2 PSU power panic cables) have different diameters. Is it better to use one connector (6 pin) or two connectors (4 pin, 2 pin)?

Comment: If you use two connectors, what can happen if only one is plugged in?

Comment: I would only use it when all cables are connected. My main concern is that it is difficult to connect the 2 power panic cables to the Sam connector as their are thinner than the power cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XT30 or XT60 connectors to sepparate the PSU from the Einsy. I have done it myself a few years ago on 4 Prusa's and it is working great. But I've only got the +/- cables, no power panic though.

Answer (score 1):

The YL connectors are rated for wires as small as AWG 26 (and as big as AWG 16). If the power panic wires are smaller than this (or the power supply wires larger) you will need to use a different connector for them. Otherwise, I do not see a problem with mixing different wire gauges in the same connector.